# Python Folding in Neovim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, folding, code-folding

For some reason folding really won't work in neovim for me. I've tried a few different folding plugins and they all just say `'E490: No fold found'` when I try to fold a code block.
Am I using it correctly? I'm going to the top of a block, eg a for loop and pressing `zc` while in normal mode.

```
" plugins
call plug#begin()
" Plug 'numirias/semshi', {'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins'}
" Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
" Plug 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
Plug 'python-mode/python-mode', { 'for': 'python', 'branch': 'develop' }
" Plug 'Konfekt/Fastfold'
call plug#end()

" custom mappings - imap: insert mode, nmap: normal mode
imap jk <Esc>
nmap <C-o> o<Esc>k

" show relative and absolute line numbers
:set relativenumber
:set number
:set nu

" use system clipboard for copy pasting
:set clipboard=unnamedplus

colorscheme onedark
set ts=4 sw=4



"Use 24-bit (true-color) mode in Vim/Neovim when outside tmux.
"If you're using tmux version 2.2 or later, you can remove the outermost $TMUX check and use tmux's 24-bit color support
"(see < http://sunaku.github.io/tmux-24bit-color.html#usage > for more information.)
if (empty($TMUX))
  if (has("nvim"))
    "For Neovim 0.1.3 and 0.1.4 < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/2198 >
    let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
  endif
  "For Neovim > 0.1.5 and Vim > patch 7.4.1799 < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/61be73bb0f965a895bfb064ea3e55476ac175162 >
  "Based on Vim patch 7.4.1770 (`guicolors` option) < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8a633e3427b47286869aa4b96f2bfc1fe65b25cd >
  " < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Following-HEAD#20160511 >
  if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
  endif
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a plugin like [SimplyFold](https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold).

You seem to have it in your config file above, but it's commented out. Uncomment the line:

```
" Plug 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
```

Comment: By the way, I've found SimpylFold to slow down my neovim dramatically. Since OP is using NeoVim, I just wanted to point out that you can now fold python with the built-in tree-sitter library. I won't explain here how to do it, it's easy to find on the web.